# How do i make the left and right side of the border get closer to the text

Tags: html, css

I want to make the **left** and **right** side of the border of my **Autumn outfits**  header get closer to the text, with a 2px padding for each of them. I have tried to achieve this by setting the padding-left and padding-right to 2px but the element still stays the same.

Here below is a snippet of my code.

```css
.outfitsbuttonsheadings {
 padding-left: 2px;
 padding-right: 2px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 text-align: center;
 font-family:'Mali', cursive;
```

```html
<h3 class="outfitsbuttonsheadings">Autumn outfits</h3>
```

P.S. - After you have answered this question could you also please give me tips of how to ask this question better. I am new to stack overflow and i want to get better at asking questions the right way.

Comment: You've described the problem pretty well. An image of what you actually want the layout to look like is always helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `h3` element is a block element that extends across the line.

If you want the border tight around the text, you can use a `span`. The below CSS defines the class for `span` and for `h3` separately.

```css
span.outfitsbuttonsheadings {
 padding-left: 2px;
 padding-right: 2px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 font-family:'Mali', cursive;
}
  
h3.outfitsbuttonsheadings {
    text-align: center;  /* center text inside the h3 block */
}
```

```html
<h3 class="outfitsbuttonsheadings">
  <span class="outfitsbuttonsheadings">Autumn outfits</span>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert the H3 to an `inline-block` element, but that will cause not block elements to be on the same line with the header:

```css
.outfitsbuttonsheadings {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Mali', cursive;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="outfitsbuttonsheadings">Autumn outfits</h3>
<span>rest of the text</span>
```

Another option is to set the width to be `fit-content`. This will maintain the `block` display, but it's [not supported by all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Browser_compatibility).

```css
.outfitsbuttonsheadings {
  width: fit-content;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Mali', cursive;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="outfitsbuttonsheadings">Autumn outfits</h3>
<span>rest of the text</span>
```

Comment: and also the use of float and clearing after it

Comment: I had considered this approach, but it doesn't center the `h3` heading on the line as the OP was wanting.